# Bazel: Returning all providers of another Target

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

In Bazel, is there a way to access all the providers of a [Target](https://bazel.build/versions/6.2.0/rules/lib/Target?hl=en) without prior knowledge of what provider type a target could contain ?

I'd like a rule implementation to simply returns the "result" (providers) of another rule:

```
def _myrule_impl(ctx):
    for p in ctx.attr.parent_rule:
    # Error: type 'Target' is not iterable

    p = ctx.attr.target_rule.providers
    # Error: <target //:main> (rule 'other_rule') doesn't have provider 'providers'
        
    return ctx.attr.parent_rule

myrule = rule(
    implementation = _myrule_impl,
    attrs = {
        "parent_rule": attr.label(),
    }
)
```

I could reconstruct the list of providers by accessing them via their types (e.g. `ctx.attr.parent_rule[DefaultInfo]` but it's error prone and would break easily if not maintained properly (e.g. another rule upstream adds a new provider to a target not checked in `myrule` therefore breaking downstream).

It seems there must be an easy way to do that but the [documentation](https://bazel.build/versions/6.2.0/rules/lib/Target?hl=en) is not clear on exactly how the providers are stored (looks like something ad-hoc, and not a dict or list).

I'm also interested in any other alternative method for a "pass-through" rule in case there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providers are more or less considered private implementation details of rules, so there isn't a way to enumerate the providers of a target. See this comment in the code, for example:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/1f2d57631df9c61f0a15775cad72dc415a037ee4/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/configuredtargets/RuleConfiguredTarget.java#L253-L255

(that is, while `print(target)` will print provider names, doing `str(target)` in Starlark won't contain the same info, and things like `getattr` / `hasattr` don't work for providers)

This does make things like "wrapper rules" or "pass through rules" more difficult, but there are other mechanisms being implemented for this such as https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/19507